# How to prove $\operatorname{Span}(\operatorname{Span}(S)) = \operatorname{Span}(S)$

Tags: vector-spaces

Given a Subset $S$ (not necessarily a subspace) of a vector space $V$, $\operatorname{Span}(S)$ indicate the smallest subspace containing  $S$.
I need a hint to solve the problem

$$\operatorname{Span}(\operatorname{Span}(S)) = \operatorname{Span}(S)$$

Comment: To make Calvin Khor's answer more explicit, show that "a linear combination of linear combinations is a linear combination". A surprising amount of linear algebra boils down to this principle. For example, if you write it out precisely, you pretty much can't avoid discovering matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $\newcommand{\span}{\text{span}} \span (\span S)$ contains $\span S$; if you can show inclusion the other way, you win. So pick something in $\span(\span S)$, and try to show it is in $\span S$.